# How to obtain this geometric progression

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series, geometric-series

How do I obtain this from the formula of the geometric progression (which I 'only' know as $1+q+q^2+...+q^{n-1} = \frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$)?
$$\frac{x_1^p-x^p}{x_1^q-x^q} = \frac{x_1^{p-1}+x_1^{p-2}x+...+x^{p-1}}{x_1^{q-1}+x_1^{q-2}x+...+x^{q-1}}$$

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You may get it from $(a^n - b^n) = (a-b)(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^ib^{n-1-i})$

Comment: I see. However, this has nothing to do (directly) with the geometric progression, merely with some well-known identity. Is there a way to obtain it through the geometric series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** consider $q = x_1/x{}{}{}$.

$$\begin{align}
1+q+\dots + q^{n-1} &= 
1+ x_1/x+\dots + ( x_1/x)^{n-1} 
\\&= \frac 1{x^{n-1}}\left[
x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}x_1 + \dots + x_1^{n-1}
\right]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This made sense immediately. Thanks. :)
edit: even without your edit :P

Comment: nice!${{{{{}}}}}$